# How to draw columns in a TableLayout dynamically

Tags: android, layout

How to draw columns in a TableLayout dynamically, as they are in the image.

[image]

I want to pass objects of a class to create the table.

Comment: it sounds to me you should be using a RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager

Answer (score 1):

I will work with ImageView width match_parent **you need to change width**

```
<TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/t1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                   android:id="@+id/imageView"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_gravity="center"
                   app:srcCompat="@drawable/qr"/>

                <ImageView
                   android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_gravity="center"
                   app:srcCompat="@drawable/qr"/>

                <ImageView
                   android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_gravity="center"
                   app:srcCompat="@drawable/qr"/>
                <ImageView
                   android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_gravity="center"
                   app:srcCompat="@drawable/qr"/>
                <ImageView
                   android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_gravity="center"
                   app:srcCompat="@drawable/qr"/>
            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>
```

Also in your XML file make button and sit onClick attr for button

Now work with your Activity make parameter for tableLayout

```
private TableLayout t1;
```

On onCreate method prepare t1 parameter

```
t1 = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.t1);
t1.setColumnStretchable(0,true);
t1.setColumnStretchable(1,true);
t1.setColumnStretchable(2,true);
t1.setColumnStretchable(3,true);
t1.setColumnStretchable(4,true);
```

inside onClick method
declare TableRow

```
//you can declare Context with parameter and used instead of this
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
```

Now we make instance of image view

```
ImageView img1 = new ImageView(this);
ImageView img2 = new ImageView(this);
ImageView img3 = new ImageView(this);
ImageView img4 = new ImageView(this);
ImageView img5 = new ImageView(this);
```

Now we set attr for instance of image view

```
img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite);
img1.setMaxWidth(50);
img1.setMinimumWidth(30);
img1.setMaxHeight(50);
img1.setMinimumHeight(30);
img1.setForegroundGravity(Gravity.CENTER); // this is work from API23

img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite);
img2.setMaxWidth(50);
img2.setMinimumWidth(30);
img2.setMaxHeight(50);
img2.setMinimumHeight(30);
img2.setForegroundGravity(Gravity.CENTER); // this is work from API23

img3.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite);
img3.setMaxWidth(50);
img3.setMinimumWidth(30);
img3.setMaxHeight(50);
img3.setMinimumHeight(30);
img3.setForegroundGravity(Gravity.CENTER); // this is work from API23

img4.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite);
img4.setMaxWidth(50);
img4.setMinimumWidth(30);
img4.setMaxHeight(50);
img4.setMinimumHeight(30);
img4.setForegroundGravity(Gravity.CENTER); // this is work from API23

img5.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite);
img5.setMaxWidth(50);
img5.setMinimumWidth(30);
img5.setMaxHeight(50);
img5.setMinimumHeight(30);
img5.setForegroundGravity(Gravity.CENTER); // this is work from API23
```

after that we will add the imageView to row

```
tr.addView(img1);
tr.addView(img2);
tr.addView(img3);
tr.addView(img4);
tr.addView(img5);
```

finally we will add tableRow to TableLayout

```
t1.addViwe(tr);
```

No run the app
When you click in button you will add row 
you can used this code inside loop like for loop or while loop 
Good Luck